# Sylius, how to override criteria?

Tags: forms, filter, criteria, sylius

I would like to know how to add criteria in formFilter.

For example, in backend product index.
By default there is only "name" and "reference" filter. I would like to add a filter by any field.

[image]

I managed to add a custom field to the form but when I click on filter button, my custom field is ignored.

How can I fix it please ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to extend/replace 
`Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine\ORM\ProductRepository.php` with your own ProductRepositoryClass.
The method you need to modify is on line 88: `createFilterPaginator`

```
<?php 
namespace Acme\AppBundle\Doctrine\ORM;

use Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Doctrine\ORM\ProductRepository as BaseProductRepository;

class ProductRepository extends BaseProductRepository {

public function createFilterPaginator($criteria = array(), $sorting = array(), $deleted = false) 
    {
    // ... your filtering logic here.
    }
}
```

Then register it in cofiguration, so it will replace the sylius product repository.

```
sylius_product:
    resources:
        product:
            classes:
                repository: AppBundle\Entity\Product\ProductRepository
```

If you want / need to call diferent method thant the createFilterPaginator, you will have to also override the controller.